# Syntax for Duckdb > Python SQL with Parameter\Variable

Tags: python, sql, pandas, duckdb

I am working on a proof of concept, using Python and Duckdb.

I am wanting to use a variable\parameter inside the Duckdb SELECT statement.

For example,

```
y = 2
dk.query("SELECT * FROM DF WHERE x > y").to_df()
```

How can y be properly referenced?

I was not able to find any documentation\reference @ web.

Comment: Use an f string

Comment: y is a scalar value? and afterwards you make it a dataframe?

Comment: ``dk.query(f"SELECT * FROM DF WHERE x > {y}").to_df()``

Answer (score 4):

Your query looks suspicious to me; you always should use a prepared statement to pass variables to the database. It will prevent sql injection and so increase security:

```py
y = 2
con.execute("SELECT * FROM DF WHERE x > ?", [y]).df()
```

Comment: https://duckdb.org/2021/05/14/sql-on-pandas.html

Comment: stackoverflow combined 2 lines when i submitted...

Comment: sammywemmy answered it but don't see how to indicate. thanks!

Comment: it is insecure  so try mine

Comment: prepare statements require `prepare query` syntax?  https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/query_syntax/prepared_statements.html

Comment: this abouve is pythonb and not duckdb sql code, what you can see in the .df()